# DAX sum filtered by multiple columns of related tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a measure, which is being added to a table and a Card. The measure is used to show the total hours posted where Calls.[Sch Engineer]=Hours.Employee AND Calls.ProjID=Hours.ProjID

The value on each row of the table is correct. However the total value for this measure is incorrect in the table and also the Card, and I cant work out why.

So the measure is:

```
SchEngHrsOnly =
VAR main =
    MAX ( Calls[Sch Engineer] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Hours'[Hrs] ), Hours[Employee] = main )
```

When I add this to a table visual I get the following - both Table total and Card value for measure are incorrect - they should be 163.50:

[image]

If I select a row in the table visual, then the Card visual shows a correct value, otherwise it shows an incorrect value:

[image]

My data model is:

[image]

My relationships are:

[image]

What I am looking to get is:

[image]

Also, please see here the PBIX file:

[PBIX File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuiIgc_S9J5JhblwvHDPfJiF4lItYw?e=GNSl81)

Can anyone help with this issue please?

Comment: Why total=281.50 is incorrect? Now it is showing SUM. What is your expected value for the total of All Hrs? What is the formula for that measure now?

Comment: All Hours isnt relevant to the question, it can be ignored, it is there just to show the total of ALL hours posted for that Job - All Hrs = sum(Hours[Hrs])
I need to get the total of measure SchEngHrsOnly to = 163.50. This is 69.75+58+35.75. Does that make sense? I have amended the original post to remove this additional measure as it just confuses the question I think

Comment: Can you explain what is the 69.75 suppose to mean? What do you want to do? Let me guess. First you calculate MAX by category (which is ProjID or Job), then you want to get sum of that max'es, yes? So you want to calculate sum of maxes?

Comment: I am trying to SUM Hours.Hrs where Calls.[Sch Engineer]=Hours.Employee AND Calls.ProjID=Hours.ProjID. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please see my edit for FilteredSum. PS Your column names are not the same across tables [ProjID] vs [Prod ID] .

Comment: If the result of formula is ok now, I would suggest edit of your question title into something meaningful: "DAX sum of inner join" or "DAX sum filtered by multiple columns of related tables".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want SUM of MAX values, then go this way:

```
SumOfMaxes = 
SUMX(
  VALUES( Hours[ProjID] ),
  CALCULATE( MAX( Hours[Hrs]) )
)
```

It produces:

[image]

You might be also interested in:

[DAX ALLEXCEPT to sum by category of multiple dimension tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58978358/1903793)

[DAX Median of category sums](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60211761/1903793)

Edit

After your explanations I see that you want filtered sum.

```
FilteredSum = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Hours[Hrs] ),
    FILTER (
        Hours,
        Hours[Employee] = RELATED ( Calls[Sch Engineer] )
            && Hours[ProjID] = RELATED ( Calls[Proj ID] )
    )
)
```

[image]

https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2010/02/09/how-to-relate-tables-in-dax-without-using-relationships/

Comment: I am trying to SUM Hours.Hrs WHERE Calls.[Sch Engineer]=Hours.Employee AND Calls.ProjID=Hours.ProjID. SumOFMaxes measure has incorrect value for Job 423198, it should be 58.00. And the total should be 163.50

Comment: Brilliant, I couldn't think of a good way to word this question. I should have just used SQL join analogy earlier I think. This RELATED function looks VERY useful, will read up on it ASAP

Answer (score 0):

You can create it as a calculated column and then sum it up to get the value:

```
Hours Calc = CALCULATE(MAX(Hours[Hrs]),FILTER(Hours,Hours[ProjID]=Calls[ProjID]))
```

The above calculation will add a column with the maximum of hours for each project ID. Then you can sum it up in the final table and should get the desired results. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @CR7SMS Im not trying to get the MAX of Hours. Im trying to calculate the total Hours posted per Project but only for the Calls.SchEngineer per project. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, I tried this measure just in case, but I get an error:
Column 'ProjID' in table 'Calls' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression.

Comment: That might be because you have not created a relationship between the Hours and Calls table